# Scrollbars in modal prevent user action in Chrome

Tags: html, css, asp.net, modal-dialog

I have a modal dialog that loads an apsx page within it. I've got a table in my aspx page that list some customers. It's working well in Internet Explorer, however when I open it up using Google Chrome, it gives me two scrolls bar and I'm unable to select the item, note that it only happen with the first item, if I have more than two customers a can select by the second one on!

I really have no idea what it can be.

Running in IE[image].

Running in Google Chrome[image]

CODE:

### 1. Opening Dialog

```
var dialogwindow = new Mscrm.CrmDialog(Mscrm.CrmUri.create(webresourceurl), window, 598, 298);
dialogwindow.setCallbackReference(function (result) { alert(result) });
dialogwindow.show();
```

### 2. HTML Page to load aspx page

```
<form id="myForm" runat="server">
    <iframe width="590" height="280" id="IFrameCheckList" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
</form>
```

### 3. Aspx page

```
.record_table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.highlight {
     background-color: rgb(177, 214, 240);
    }

 <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Table ID="MainTable" class="record_table" runat="server">
                <asp:TableRow BackColor="White">
                    <asp:TableCell CssClass="Titulo" Width="10px">
                        <label></label>
                    </asp:TableCell>

                    <asp:TableCell CssClass="Titulo" Width="250px">
                        <label>Proponente</label>
                    </asp:TableCell>

                    <asp:TableCell CssClass="Titulo" Width="130px">
                        <label>Tipo de Participação</label>
                    </asp:TableCell>

                    <asp:TableCell CssClass="Titulo" Width="90px">
                        <label> Participação</label>
                    </asp:TableCell>

                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
        </div>

        <asp:Button CssClass="ConfirmButton" Style="padding: 0 0 0 0; border-radius:5px" ID="btnConfirmar" Text="Confirmar" runat="server" OnClientClick="btnConfirmarOnClick(); return false;" />

    </form>
```

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: We can't see what is causing the problem without the relevant code to do so. Please post the HTML and CSS afflicted with the box.